# Installed Windows 8.1 now display driver is not installed automatically

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, drivers

One of the things I love from Windows 7 and 8 is that it will install perfectly functional drivers for your devices.

Anyway, I have this 'old' laptop, it's a Toshiba that originally came with Windows 7. I had to format with Windows 8.1, the sound is working, the network is working, but I'm stuck with a generic video driver that doesn't let me change my resolution and it's stuck in 1024 x 768.

Laptop model is **Toshiba Satellite L505D-SP6905R**

I've tried installing the video drivers that are for Win 7 but they just don't install.

Any idea how can I get a generic ATI video driver or how can I help Windows detect a proper driver so I can use my GPU properly?

Comment: [Toshiba Satellite L505D SP6905R Display Adapter Drivers for Windows 8.1](http://cbasoft.com/drivers/drivers_Toshiba_Satellite-L505D-SP6905R_Display-Adapter_Windows-8.1.html) - use at your own risk

Comment: "One of the things I love from Windows 7 and 8 is that it will install perfectly functional drivers for your devices." Uhh yeah -- this just isn't true IME. :)  Have you tried going to ATI and downloading the Windows 8 drivers from them?

Comment: Yes, but their tool doesn't even recognize my videocard!

Comment: @DavidPostill In the end, to be able to "download the latest driver" you had to pay 39 USD, for a driver that I don't know if will actually work hehe

Comment: @JuanBonnett Ah. I never went that far ... :/

Comment: Well, I might need to get a copy of Windows 7 or use Ubuntu...

Comment: So just download the Intel/AMD/Nvidia driver from Intel/AMD/Nvidia driver.  Why would anyone pay for a driver disk when the driver is free?  If I knew which GPU/iGPU you had I would just link you to the driver itself.